# Add button in React JS which populates a table dynamically from backend api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uitableview, onclick, frontend

I am new to Front end development and I've to make changes in an existing ReactJS code. What i am supposed to do is introduce a new button on home page which on click shows a table whose data is fetched from an api end point.
The UI view for both before button click and after click should be same, the only addition being table after clicking button.
So far i am just able to introduce code which fetches data from end point but i don't know how to introduce the table and populate it.
This is a sudo picture that might explain what i am trying to do.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi8HB.png)

Hopefully the question makes sense. I appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you in advance.

Here's the code that i've :

```js
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      apiResponse: '',
      username: '',
      detailsData: [],
    };
  }

  callAPI() {
    fetch(‘/userData')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ username: res.username }))
      .catch(err => err);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.callAPI();
  }

  launch = () => {
    const { username } = this.state;
    const newTab = window.open();
    fetch('/LoginUrl')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.info(username);
      })
      .catch(err => err);
  };

//This is where is want to get the table and populate it from the end point
//I can see the data fetched for the endpoint in Network response
  detailButton = async () => {
  fetch(‘/userDetails')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      if (res.error) {
        this.showToast(res.error);
        this.setState({ detailsData: [] });
      } else {
        this.setState({ detailsData: res.data, isOpen: false });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => err);
};



  pageView() {
    return (
      <div style={{ float: 'center', textAlign: 'center', fontFamily: 'system-ui,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif' }}>
        <h1>Hello {this.state.username}</h1>
        <br />
        <Button
          label="Launch”
          variant="brand"
          onClick={this.launch}
        />
        <Button
          label=“Details”
          variant="brand"
          onClick={this.detailButton}
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        {this.detailView()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: please try to attach some code of what you tried so far and where actually you are facing the issue with ...

Comment: I've made the edit and added code that i've so far.
hope that helps